# Public variable used for form opening not feeding through to from

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, variables

Having some issues getting a form to populate based on a variable determined in current form.

I have a search result form that has a datagrid with all results, with an open form button for each row. When the user clicks this, the rowindex is used to pull out the ID of that record, which then feeds to the newly opened form and populates based on a SQL stored procedure run using the ID as a paramter.

However, at the moment the variable is not feeding through to the form, and am lost as to why that is. Stored procedure runs fine if i set the id within the code. Here is my form open code, with sci

```vb
Public Class SearchForm
    Dim Open As New FormOpen
    Dim data As New SQLConn
    Public scid As Integer

    Private Sub Search_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim sql As New SQLConn
        Call sql.SearchData()

        dgvSearch.DataSource = sql.dt.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvSearch_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSearch.CellContentClick
        Dim rowindex As Integer
        Dim oform As New SprinklerCardOpen

        rowindex = e.RowIndex.ToString
        scid = dgvSearch.Rows(rowindex).Cells(1).Value
        TextBox1.Text = scid

        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            oform.Show()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The form opening then has the follwing:

```vb
Private Sub SprinklerCard_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Populate fields from SQL

    Try
        Call Populate.SprinklerCardPopulate(ID)
        cboInsured.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
        txtAddress.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)
        txtContactName.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3)
        txtContactPhone.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4)
        txtContactEmail.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(5)
        numPumps.Value = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6)
        numValves.Value = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(7)
        cboLeadFollow.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(8)
        cboImpairment.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(9)
        txtComments.Text = Populate.dt.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(10)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString & "SCID = " & ID)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get that variable ID passed to the Populate method?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the SCID variable to be accessed from your SprinklerCardOpen form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ID` variable in the form before you open it.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    oform.ID = scid
    oform.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple, been looking at this for what seems like hours and missed that.